# How to change the SplitView from left,right to top,bottom on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I know that the SplitView is new to iPad, it split the screen with left and right. But I want to split the screen with top and bottom. How can I do so? thank u.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that, and the width of left pane is fixed at 320. If you want to split the screen with top and bottom, you should write your own view controller rather than using UISplitViewController.